# What does the "this" keyword mean in JavaScript with a + before it

Tags: javascript, node.js

The code for this is not mine. I was just going over something and saw a + before the keyword this for the first time and was wondering what it does.

```
                +this.closest('li').getAttribute('data-index');
```

Comment: Re edit: (Except in the most literal sense) the `+` isn't before `this`, it is before the entire rest of the expression: `this.closest('li').getAttribute('data-index')`

Comment: @ZlatanOmerović — Answers are better posted as answers, not comments.